# Ubuntu installation for specific usage

Tags: 12.04, installation, nvidia, dual-boot, windows-7

I want to install a latest or optimum version of Ubuntu as a dual boot with my Windows 7, 64-bit. I want to install Ubuntu to run OpenFOAM which is an open source CFD software. My computer Specs are as follows, any advice is well appreciated. Thanks.

> Lenovo G460
>  Windows 7 Home Premium (x64) Service Pack 1 
>   2.13 gigahertz Intel Core i3 M 330
>  Installed RAM: 4.00 GB(3.87 GB usable) DDR3
>  NVIDIA GeForce 310M [Display adapter]
>  Dedicated
>   Video memory: 512 MB DDR3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

Answer (score 0):

You can install LTS version 12.04 or you can install 13.04 if you don't care about LTS.

For installing OPENFOAM use this command:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openfoam220
```

More details: Read [this](http://www.openfoam.org/download/ubuntu.php).